# How do I disable past dates and future dates using react-calender?

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I have tried various ways to implement it but all I could do is disable specifics days in the calendar. I want to disable future date and disable all previous dates from today.

Comment: So why you need to use the calendar ?

Comment: Here some examples : https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar/wiki/Recipes#selectively-disable-tiles

Comment: thank you for your reply. I was trying out this appointment project where the admin can disable future dates so that the user cannot book on those dates.

Answer (score 3):

Imad salki's answer disables current date as well.
and if you only want to disable past dates use following method

<Calendar minDate={new Date()} />

Answer (score 0):

To disable past dates you declare this function :

```
const tileDisabled = ({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => {
   return date < new Date()
}
```

and then you pass it to you calandar like this :

```
<Calendar tileDisabled={tileDisabled} />
```

if you want to disbale all the dates (past and future) your function have to return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState("");

  const disablePastDates = () => {
    var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var disableDates = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    setDate(disableDates);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    disablePastDates();
  }, []);
```